# Only In IE11, template gets rendered twice time ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

Created the application using ReactJS. Application template render behavior is working fine in all the browser except IE11, In IE11 shows the same template twice. Below is my code and schreent shot. How to get rid out of this kind of issue.

```
render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <div>Hello</div>
    </div>
    );
  }
```

Below a screenshot from the Chrome Browser.
[image]

Below A screenshot from the IE11, why in IE Hello template rendering twice time?

[image]

Comment: I made a demo using your provided code in stackblitz and it runs well in IE. You could check [my demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xhpkpj) in IE. Have you used F12 dev tools to check the elements in IE and see if there's any error in console? You could try to clear cache in IE and reload the page to see if it solves the problem.

Comment: @YuZhou Thanks for your solution. The issue was with some unwanted tag data binding.

Comment: You could post your solution and mark it as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.